# Who exactly is Rājā Citra here in Rig Veda 8.21.18.?

Tags: rig-veda, indra, shloka, inner-meaning, chitragupta

Sanskrit text [Accents, Plain, Transliterated].:

> चित्र॒ इद्राजा॑ राज॒का इद॑न्य॒के य॒के सर॑स्वती॒मनु॑ । प॒र्जन्य॑ इव त॒तन॒द्धि वृ॒ष्ट्या स॒हस्र॑म॒युता॒ दद॑त् ॥

> चित्र इद्राजा राजका इदन्यके यके सरस्वतीमनु । पर्जन्य इव ततनद्धि वृष्ट्या सहस्रमयुता ददत् ॥

> citra id rājā rājakā id anyake yake sarasvatīm anu | parjanya iva tatanad dhi vṛṣṭyā sahasram ayutā dadat ||

English translation.:

> “Verily the Rājā Citra, giving his thousands and tens of thousands, has overspread (with his bounty)those other petty princes, who rules along the Sarasvatī, as Parjanya (overspeads the earth) with rain.”

Source.: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/rig-veda-english-translation/d/doc836014.html

1. Is Rājā Citra none other than Lord Chitragupta in context.?
2. Please elaborate the Shloka on what it seems to suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think,** here Citra is not a name but the quality of a King, which is "wonderful and giving" in nature.

R.V. 4.32.2.:

> भृमिश्चिद्घासि तूतुजिरा **चित्र** चित्रिणीष्वा । **चित्रं** कृणोष्यूतये ॥
>
> “**Wonderful** Indra, wanderer at times (through space), you are verily **the granter of (our) desires,** and do what is marvellous for the protection (of those who are engaged) in **wondrous** works.”

R.V. 6.6.7.:

> स **चित्र चित्रं** चितयन्तमस्मे चित्रक्षत्र चित्रतमं वयोधाम् । चन्द्रं रयिं पुरुवीरं बृहन्तं चन्द्र चन्द्राभिर्गृणते युवस्व ॥
>
> “**Wonderful Agni, of wonderful strength, bestower of delight, grant to us,** and to him who praises you with gratifying (praises), wonderful, most wonderful riches, conferring fame, supplying food, comprehending male descendants,d electable and infinite.”

Commentary by Sāyaṇa: Ṛgveda-bhāṣya.:

> Not the repetition of the **word citra (wonderful)** and candra (delightful).

So, most probably it talks about the King who is Wonderful (Citra) in nature and gives thousands and thousands of gifts to his people like the clouds gives rains.

As you can also see in details of R.V. 8.21.18 that the Devatā (deity/subject-matter) is citrasya dānastutiḥ.

I hope this helps. Prd..

Comment: That's a really great answer however, what still bothers me is why the translation doesn't seems to directly translate Citra as "wonderful". Are there any other sources or bhasyas that could strengthen the thought?

Comment: No, that's completely my analysis after some research. If u see the previous verse there citra is used as as individual who gives along with Indra and Saraswati and in this verse it's explained who citra is. "A King". Even if u see the details u can see along with deity, subject-matter is also given. So, from that we can conclude citra is not an individual but an identifying quality of a king. I hope this helps.